Any platform places to share code (simulations) about math/physics objects?
In math, it is very convenient to code programs that simulate the objects we study to give us more intuition.

Q: I was just wondering if there are any website-databases that have attempted to collect those programs i.e. I am thinking something analogous to https://www.scilag.net/ for open problems.

Even if they still have small visibility, I would like to support them by uploading my code there.
Currently the options I see are: Matlab's platform, Github, personal-websites (did I miss any?).  The Matlab-option is a bit restrictive because sometimes it is better to use C++. The personal-websites-option is good but sometimes websites go down and so does their code. The Github-option is the main one used currently but I think it gets a bit chaotic because it is combined with all other possible programs out there.

You could use Zenodo. It is backed by CERN, so likely to keep long-term accessibility. Code depositories receive a DOI, to make it easier to cite and it supports various license types and a great variety of data types (this includes GitHub).
Indeed, Zenodo is a generic repository, but to make the math/physics simulations findable you could either include a link in the publication that makes use of these, or set up a dedicated web page that collects the links. If you point the Wayback Machine to that web page the long-term accessibility is also guaranteed.
